# How to call a non-static method from one Activity to another activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities &  i want to call a method clear from B. 
I tried like this and I am getting null pointer exceptions.

```
class A extends Activity {
    ...
    public void clear(){}

}

class B extends Activity{
    public void clearData() {
        A a=new A();
        a.clear();
    }        
}
```

Comment: Just create an **AppActivity**, and extend it in your both the activities A and B. Now place this function in this new activity. Its easily accessible to you.

Comment: You cannot create a new object of your activity class , just get the current instance of the A Activity and call `clear()` on that instance

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
class A extends Activity{
static A instance;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    instance = this;
}

public static A getInstance() {
    return instance;
}
....
public void clear(){}

}
```

and in class B:

```
class B extends Activity {
  public void  clearData(){
      A a = A.getInstance();
      a.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, I didn't know that `non-static methods` can be called like this. I don't know why people downvote such answers.

Comment: You have made it as static, So in future will be any memory leak in heap or PermGem memory?

Comment: @MadhusudhanAradya yes, there will definitely be memory leaks, as the static variable will hold onto `Activity` context, even when `Activity` no longer exists. It was the best solution I could come up at that time. I will be updating this answer in the future with more efficient solutions for sure.

Comment: @Aman Grover is there any optimized solution for calling the function without making it static

Comment: @MadhusudhanAradya you can make your own listeners, which are basically interfaces, to call a method from another activity.