# How to send a function from Fragment class to another class in Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I'm stuck in a program need some help. I have a fragment class in which I have multiple functions but I need only one function from it in the other class this class is not a fragment class. I used **Intent** but through that I'm not able to pass any function. the sample code is below. I need the **ReadData** whole function in the other class. as the value of data is changing in every second so i want it in the other screen to display

```
public class ModeFragment extends Fragment implements TitledFragment {
    public void readData(){
        if(manager.getConnectedDevices().size()<=0){
            Toast.makeText(ModeFragment.this.getActivity(),"No connected devices", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        device1 = manager.getConnectedDevices().get(0);
        Map<String , String> reciveData =  getSpecificServiceInfo(device1 , CHARACTERISTIC_READABLE);
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : reciveData.entrySet()){
            manager.read(device1, e.getKey(), e.getValue(), new BleReadCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onRead(byte[] data, BleDevice device) {
                    Toast.makeText(ModeFragment.this.getActivity(), "Read success!   data:  " + new String(data), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                    String str = data.toString();
//                    List<String> data1 = Arrays.asList(str.split(","));

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity() , BluetoothActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("data" , data.toString());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFail(int failCode, String info, BleDevice device) {
//                    Toast.makeText(ModeFragment.this.getActivity(), "Read fail!   data:  " + info, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
        }

    }
private void onclick(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(ModeFragment.this.getActivity() ,  BluetoothActivity.class);       
    intent.putExtra("key" , "value of Key");
    startActivity(intent);}}
```

Other class:

```
public class BluetoothActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ModeFragment modeFragment = new ModeFragment();
    modeFragment.readData();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String str = intent.getStringExtra("key");
    sensor_1_value.setText(str);
    Toast.makeText(BluetoothActivity.this , str , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

but through intent I only get this specific Value.

Comment: You should use an interface to call back to the activity rather than starting the same activity with a new intent, you may find many examples [like this](https://android.jlelse.eu/how-to-communicate-between-fragments-and-activities-dc91707e02fb)

Comment: Also your code snippet looks like you are listening for data from some service. If it is a long running operation consider using components like [Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)

Comment: I'm reading the data from the BLE Server.

Comment: Use interfaces or  you can use static methods

Comment: static ModeFragment modeFragment;

    public static ModeFragment getInstance(){
        return modeFragment;
    }

     in Other Class:


    public void getData_from_mode(){

        ModeFragment modeFragment = ModeFragment.getInstance();
        modeFragment.readData();

    }

Comment: but it's also not working. I use this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39489482/how-to-call-a-non-static-method-from-one-activity-to-another-activity/39489645

Comment: Error:::      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.grng.rthr.main.ui.fragment.atWork.ModeFragment.readData()' on a null object reference